# Guidance towards exploit development and exploring codes

Tags: exploit, exploit-development

I am familiar with intel assembly ,c programming ,perl and linux kernel internals.

I want to explore more through fuzzing , analyzing source code and developing exploits as well as proper safety patches in near my future.

I need some guidance from everyone as i have no one to ask .... :-( , and Google searches are making me crazy (searching from last few months.)

1.What steps i should take ?

2.Any certificate courses i should go through?

3.Some books to start as a beginner?

4.Some forums name where i can discuss and get help from people around the globe?

5.Any other information that would help me ?

Comment: This url will give the best step by step explanation of how to go about it:http://www.myne-us.com/2010/08/from-0x90-to-0x4c454554-journey-into.html

Answer (score 2):

Let's us discuss the paths you have :

1-**Self study path**: you can start with Georgia weidman's great book
**[Penetration Testing: A Hands-On Introduction to Hacking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593275641)**
If you're interested in exploit development only, you can jump directly to the exploit development chapter in the book (which i -and i'm talking from experience - don't recommend ).
Next you can go with "[**Gray Hat Hacking: The Ethical Hacker's Handbook**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071832386)".
You can also use "[**The Shell coders' Handbook**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047008023X)" 
And finally, you can use [Corlan's](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/articles/) and [FuzzSecurity's](http://www.fuzzysecurity.com/tutorials.html) tutorials which are awesome.

2-**Certificates' path** :

A- **SANS**' : Assuming you don't have background in ethical hacking, i would recommend starting with [SEC560](https://www.sans.org/course/network-penetration-testing-ethical-hacking) (Which is not directly related to ED) then move to [SEC660](https://www.sans.org/course/advanced-penetration-testing-exploits-ethical-hacking) which is an indepth course on advanced Penetration Testing (including Exploit development)  and finally you can move to [SEC760](https://www.sans.org/course/advance-exploit-development-pentetration-testers) 
(Advanced exploit development)

***Advantages*** : Indepth, good instructors , practical and you can take the training Online or onsite

***Disadvantages*** : very expensive (compared to other courses ) and their exams are MCQ based

B-**Offensive security** : 
You can start with [OSCP](https://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/oscp-offensive-security-certified-professional/) which is penetration testing course with introduction on basic exploit development.
Then move to [OSCE](https://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-training/cracking-the-perimeter/) which is an exploit development and web hacking course 
,and finally go for [AWE](https://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-training/advanced-windows-exploitation/) which is an advanced exploitation course.

***Advantages***: hands-on training , pushes you to your limits , their exam's system is very interesting (you will have to hack machines in order to pass) 
And finally , moderate prices.

***Disadvantages*** : sometime you might find the course's offical material not enough and have to dig on your own , and the other problem is that not all the courses are available online.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can start by categorizing the exploitation techniques you are interested in, like, server exploitations, web client exploitations, local area network users exploitations, database exploitations, mobile device exploitations etc. Then, find the most important tools of each category you wish and start getting involved with tutorials and experimenting. It might sound odd, but kali linux is a good start, because it contains loads of tools for many different categories and of course the metasploit framework. Since you know perl, you will be able to run your own exploits with or without those tools easily. Make sure you also have some other VM's to exploit with widely used OS's for server and for everyday use (windows, ubuntu (and/or server edition), debian etc.)

2) Check the Offensive Security Certifications and SANS

3) @HSN gave you some very good reading material. I will also add:  [Hacking: The Art of Exploitation by Jon Erickson](https://www.nostarch.com/hacking2.htm)

4) Stack Exchange :)

5) Exploitation techniques sometimes require some specific knowledge coming from fields like networks, malicious cryptography and reverse engineering. Make sure you learn some basic stuff as you progress. Apart from giving you better unerstanding of what you use and why it works as it does, it will really help you make your own exploits way more powerful and complete.